# line integrals explanation

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, line-integrals

I am very new to this so sorry if it is obvious.

Compute the line integral $\int Fdr $ where $F(x,y)=(x^2y,y^2x)$; $r(t)=(\cos t,\sin t)$; $t\in[0,2\pi]$.

So what I would do is find $r'(t)=(-\sin t,\cos t)$ and $$\int Fdr=\int F(r(t))r'(t)dt=\int (\cos ^2(t)\sin (t), \sin ^2(t)\cos (t))(-\sin (t), \cos (t))dt=\int (-\cos ^2(t)\sin ^2(t) +\sin ^2(t)\cos ^2(t))dt=0$$

Comment: The command ´\int \limits_{a}^{b}` yields $\int \limits_{a}^{b}$.

Comment: It should be $$\int F\mathrm dr=\int \limits_0^{2\pi}\left\langle F(r(t)),r'(t)\right\rangle,$$ where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ denotes the inner product. I'm assuming you know this. But then, on the next equality you should have $F(r(t))$ and you don't. Why?

Comment: sorry can you write out what you mean please

Comment: What is $F(r(t))$?

Comment: ohhh will edit it soon. ill let you know when I done it.

Comment: Is it $$F(r(t))=(\cos ^2(t)\sin (t), \sin ^2(t)\cos (t))$$?

Comment: Yes. Proceed.${}$

Comment: I edited the main post. Can you just tell me if it is OK.